# How to efficiently subtract years from dates in python?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am **subtracting** `years` from `date column` in **Python** which felt a lot slower than **R** which is usually not the case, so I am wondering is there a faster/ efficient way of doing this in **python** ?

(As after years of working in **R** I am moving back to **python**, so my python skills are not good anymore & looking for code optimization in python).

### python code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

import time
```

Data I am showing below is just dummy to give an idea about `date format` I am working with (**Row count** in my original data is: **466285**).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_str': ['Apr-84','Mar-66','May-85']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_str'], format = '%b-%y')
```

As I was getting some wrong dates in years terms like `year: 2066, 2085` etc. so wrote a small function to correct dates as per my need:

```
# year subtraction function
def date_correction(x):
    if x > pd.to_datetime('2017-12-01'):
        x = (x - pd.to_timedelta(100 * 365.24, unit='d')) 
    else:
        x = x
        
    return x

start = time.time()
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(date_correction)
end = time.time()

print("Time taken: ", end - start)
```

`Time taken:  32.958526611328125`

Above time is in seconds I think, as it took a lot of time in completing this and that made me to time this in R as well.

### R code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)
```

```
df = data.frame(date_str = c('Apr-84','Mar-66','May-85'))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::my(date_str))
```

subtract & time operation:

```
mbm <- microbenchmark( 'date_subt' = {
  df <- df %>% 
        mutate(date = if_else( 
                                         df$date > ymd('2017-12-01'),
                                         df$date %m-% years(100),
                                         df$date
                                        ))
                                      }
                      )
```

```
mbm
```

results:

```
Unit: milliseconds

expr      min      lq       mean     median    uq       max      neval
date_subt 324.3357 331.2416 372.4745 338.8745  396.3026 744.4625 100
```

```
autplot(mbm)
```

[image]

Comment: The first optimization I can see would be calculating the 2017-12-01 and 100 years datetime objects outside of the function. Doing so makes the calculation go about 10x faster (tested using 100000 elements in the dataframe).

Comment: I was only looking for `vectorized` approach in `python` as there was a huge difference in R & python time execution which made me wonder about my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized way using boolean mask and `DateOffset`:

```
df.update(df.loc[df['date'] > '2017-12-01', 'date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=100)
```

A more concise way (without `update`)

```
df.loc[df['date'] > '2017-12-01', 'date'] -= pd.DateOffset(years=100)
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien, I thought by using `.apply()` I have vectorized it in `python` but I guess I was wrong there. Thanks again for sharing the code. Appreciate ur help !

Comment: Unfortunately, `apply` is a convenient way for a loop (almost)

Comment: yes you are right !!

Comment: And it took `Time taken:  0.00697779655456543` seconds this time.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try your code running with timedelta?

like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
if dt > pd.to_datetime('2017-12-01'):
    dt -= timedelta(years=100)
```

Comment: I was getting an error on trying `dt -= timedelta(years=100)` as there is no argument years so tried with days instead: `x -= dt.timedelta(days=100 * 365.24)` and again it took `Time taken:  32.42573404312134` seconds. thanks for suggesting me this approach but this is also lot slower than R operation

Comment: alright.. i think Corralien approach is best practice